# We're approaching the 90 day mark in public beta. What do you think we're doing well, and what do you think we could do better?

Tags: discussion

Computational Science Stack Exchange has been live for almost three months now. We've had encouraging feedback from Stack Exchange staff, and the quality of both questions and answers has been excellent for the most part.

I'd like to thank mbq for shepherding the site through the Area 51 proposal process, my co-moderators Aron Ahmadia and David Ketcheson for their thoughtful input (David especially for being such a strong advocate of the site and the community), the active users on this site for their participation, users of this site who are moderators on other sites for their guidance and support on moderating issues, and users of this site who are active on other Stack Exchange sites for their guidance on how to grow as a site, as well as for being ambassadors for Computational Science on sites like Stack Overflow.

That all said, it's time to reflect on what we've done so far. What do you think we've done well? What do you think we can do better?

Comment: I'm curious, was there any feedback from the SE team at the 90 day mark?

Comment: From what I've gathered in conversations with the SE team before the 90 day mark, the basic idea was that our answer quality is high (keep it up, guys!), and our site growth is good. We still need to continue to grow the site (more users, more active users, more users with high rep, more visits, more questions per day, and more answers per question) before we can get an actual launch, so we're still firmly in beta.

Comment: I think the answer ratio is excellent for a site with such a broad scope.  There's a great variety of advanced questions and (unlike with other sites except maybe SO) no single user is likely to be able to answer most question.  At Mathematica.SE I think every regular would be able to contribute *something* to more than half of the question (if asked to), here that is quite unlikely because there's a bigger variety of questions and some can be quite involved.

Answer (score 6):

I think for now we need to continue to get the word out, educate users about the site, and continue to promote diversity of questions and experts.  I am thinking about giving a short presentation about resources for self-taught computational scientists through our University's skills laboratory.  Would a couple of slides describing the purpose of this site, how to ask and answer questions, and how to get more help be useful for others?

Comment: Yeah, I think that'd be great!